# How to implement Java Interface (for Kafka) in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

How to implement `ConsumerRebalanceListener` using Scala?

```
public class SaveOffsetsOnRebalance implements ConsumerRebalanceListener {
}
```

And what would be example of that newly made Scala rebalance listener when subscribing to topics?

Trying to learn and wrap my mind around implementing Java methods/interfaces in Scala..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just extend the interface directly

```
class MyListener extends ConsumerRebalanceListener {
     ...
 }
```

And the example from API docs would look like:

```
  class SaveOffsetsOnRebalance(consumer: Consumer[_, _] ) extends ConsumerRebalanceListener {

   def onPartitionsRevoked(partitions: Collection[TopicPartition]): Unit = {
       // save the offsets in an external store using some custom code not described
   partitions.toScala.forEach(
         saveOffsetInExternalStore(consumer.position(partition))
   )
   }

   def onPartitionsAssigned(partitions: Collection[TopicPartition]): Unit = {
       // read the offsets from an external store using some custom code not described here
       partitions.forEach(
          consumer.seek(partition, readOffsetFromExternalStore(partition)))
   }
 }
```

Just add proper imports

Comment: Shiash What is `(consumer Consumer[_, _] )` taking as parameters?

Comment: Thanks. So the type that is passed is of type `Consumer`? Is a `Consumer` a class? This part looks like a map `[_, _]`. I am just not familiar with this notation (does `_` means `any`?) and where to look for `Consumer` to see the that type? Thanks..

Comment: The Consumer type is taken from the api documentation example. All the code snippet I took from there just translated into Scala syntax. [_, _] in Scala is equivalent to java <?, ?>, basically a generic with 2 type parameters which you don’t care what they are

Answer (score 0):

There are traits in Scala corresponding to interfaces in Java. Scala trait gets converted to Java Interfaces internally. And just like we *implement interfaces in Java*, the same way we *extend traits in Scala*. So you just need to extend that Java interfaces as if it were a Scala trait because under the hood both are same.

```
class SaveOffsetsOnRebalance extends ConsumerRebalanceListener {}
```